# windows discriminate java processids

Tags: java, windows, process

I'm developing a web application with Eclipse and Tomcat on windows. When testing my efforts I sometimes crash Tomcat, and the only option left is to kill the jvm hosting Tomcat, but that can only be done with windows' task manager.
The process to kill is a java process but eclipse is also on a java process and basically the only thing I can do determine which java process to kill is toss a coin and hope for the best. It seems that I choose the wrong (eclipse) java process more often than the tomcat java process. Of course I can and should write down the id of the only java before starting Tomcat but that is sometimes forgotten

Is there a way to determine which java process is for eclipse and which for Tomcat? when eclipse is up an running for a long time I can discriminate on the cpu time, but for short running instances this is no candidate for heurstics.

Comment: Does the command line column in task manager tell you? I had the same problem with w3wp.exe processes.

Comment: @Preet I'm not sure how to display the command line column (I'm on windows XP). I can display a couple of columns for a process but I haven't found any suitable for determining.

Comment: you got to the menu. Click  View | Select Columns and choose Command Line from the list (it's near the bottom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) which is free and I can easily see in its GUI (in process tree view) that eclipse is a super node of Tomcat's JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Process Explorer* from Sysinternals. It shows the hirarchy of processes, and since the Tomcat got started by Eclipse, you can see it as a “subprocess”.

Comment: It also shows the command line used to launch the process so you know exactly what java app is running. This is the only right answer to this question :) Process Explorer is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You could start jvisualvm from the bin of your JDK directory. There each MainClass is listed with the corresponding pid.